# Testing Drush Commands

Tags: drush, testing

How to test custom implemented Drush Commands ? Are there any Open Source Examples for Drush Commands with Unit Tests or something like that ?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.drupal.org/project/contentserialize/issues/3114142

Answer (score 3):

There are a few [test traits](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/tree/11.x/src/TestTraits) from drush package, that you can re-use.

As an example check the [migration_tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools) module. It contains a few PHPUnit tests for drush commands:

- [Functional tests](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_tools/-/tree/6.0.x/tests/src/Functional) - shows how to use [DrushTestTrait.php](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/11.x/src/TestTraits/DrushTestTrait.php)
- [Kernel tests](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_tools/-/tree/6.0.x/tests/src/Kernel)

In addition you can have a look at [tests inside the drush package](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/tree/11.x/tests).

**Update:**

As @cilefen mentioned in the comment, there is a [documentation section about unit tests](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/tree/master/tests#drush-test-traits) at drush github page.

Comment: Yes and see also https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/tree/master/tests#drush-test-traits.